# Is it possible to install addition locale in the nitrous.io's box?

Tags: nitrousio

I see alot of supported locales in my box:

```
$ less /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
```

but installed only en_US:

```
$ locale -a

C  
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

How can I add additional locales?